# Ajax call module function

Tags: 7, ajax

I need to make asynchronous page requests on *every* page load using AJAX, the idea being that a function in my module is called even when pages are cached.

The only documentation I've been able to find (Drupal 7) is for form handling using AJAX and handling links.

**How do I call a module function from a custom AJAX request? Would I just implement hook_menu() and write a custom ajax request or is there a better way of doing this in Drupal 7?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer depends on what that ajax call does, and if it is for a 'one site use' or for a contribution module.

If it s for a contribution module hook_menu might be the only way to go.

Though if it s just for a 'one site use' i would just add a *JS snippet* in your `page.tpl.php` or even `html.tpl.php` that launches the Ajax query. This would work on every page even when if cached.

**EDIT**
Actually you could also use the page preprocess function and add a js file to all your pages.

Comment: Yes that is the plan, although I'll still be doing it in the module... what I'm wondering is if I should write the request manually (i.e. $.get()) or can use Drupal API for this

Comment: Well if you know how to write the Jquery yourself i would definitely do that, you ll gain a little performance and avoid a couple of headaches.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar, but couldnt get hook_menu get working with ajax. as explained here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11330/ajax-reload-of-block-on-an-event. any idea on this?